# How can I add two projects. Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio

I just created a project so my Solution Explorer looks like this:
[image: solnexplorer]
<sub>(source: [kalleload.net](http://www.kalleload.net/uploads/gwdgdm/yszoerpnieed.jpg))</sub>

But I want to add another project which is related to this project but it's going to be a class library and it's going to output a DLL that I could use in any other project.

So how can I create a "solution" with multiple projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a related information:

There is also an option called "Always show solution" (in Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions). When enabled, the solution is always shown, even if there is only 1 project.

Answer (score 2):

**File -> Add -> New project..**